# background image of body tag is not visible

Tags: html, css, image

It does show background color and top div tag but background image is not visible up. I'm pretty new at html and css so kindly explain a little too.

here is my html and css code

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.giphy.com/media/H75Lo6V4M5pWrDo8mZ/giphy.webp") no-repeat;
  background-color: Linen;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Train of Thoughts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <h3 style="float: left">M</h3>
    <h3 style="float: right">F</h3>
  </div>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: because background color overwrite background image, try this:`background: Linen url("https://i.giphy.com/media/H75Lo6V4M5pWrDo8mZ/giphy.webp") no-repeat;`

Comment: can you tell how to adjust the background image to screen

Comment: what do you mean with _adjust the background image to screen_?

Comment: like it covers the the whole browser screen?

Comment: simply replace background-image with background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
    html{
}
body{
background: url("https://i.giphy.com/media/H75Lo6V4M5pWrDo8mZ/giphy.webp") no-repeat;
background-color: Linen;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.top{
    background-color: Black;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: White;
    border: solid 5px Black;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Train of Thoughts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <h3 style="float: left">M</h3>
        <h3 style="float: right">F</h3>
    </div>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he can use also background color , just use background property

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
background-size: cover;
```

which will stretch the image to cover the page, but since the resolution of the gif is rather different than the screens, it will look kinda weird.

Also, the no-repeat is the reason, it doesnt show at all. Without it, it will show, but several times next to each other.